# Order of operands class and enum(int) when overloading operators in C#

Tags: c#, class, enums, operator-overloading

In C++ the order of of operand evaluation is *unspecified*, what do I need to be aware of when I try overload an operator in C#.

```cs
class A{

  public static A operator +(A left, int right){
    left.someVariable += right;
    return left;
  }

  public static A operator +(A left, B right){
    var x = 1<<right; // Just to clarify that it might not be a simple int + int operation
    left.someVariable += x;
    return left;
  }
}
enum B{a=0,b=1,c=2}

var a = new A()+B.a+B.b+B.c;//I want this to be operator+(A,1<<0 + 1<<1 + 1<<2)
var b = (new A()+B.a)+B.b+B.c;//as well as this
var c = ((new A()+B.a)+B.b)+B.c;//and this
```

Resharper tells me that I can remove the parentheses in `var b=...` and `var c=...`, but I am unsure if that is correct, as I am not sure if it is guaranteed to always call the overloaded operator +(A,B) and not somewhere evaluate this as

```cs
var d = new A()+((int)B.a+((int)B.b+(int)B.c)); //operator+(A, 0+1+2)
```

**Update**

The following is from the C language specification and does not hold for C# as pointed out by PetSerAl.

<strike>Reading: [Precedence and Order of Evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)
I am pretty sure a,b,c are not guaranteed to be evaluated left to right.</strike>

> Direction of evaluation does not affect the results of expressions that include more than one multiplication (*), addition (+), or binary-bitwise (& | ^) operator at the same level. Order of operations is not defined by the language. The compiler is free to evaluate such expressions in any order, if the compiler can guarantee a consistent result.

Comment: In C# `+` have left associativity, thus `a+b+c` is equivalent to `(a+b)+c`. But, IMHO, more important: operators should not make visible changes in arguments.

Comment: @PetSerAl, but doesn't the quoted text from the msdna site explicitly say this does not hold for more than one addition operator at the same level?

Comment: That citation is from `C` language, but not `C#`.

Comment: @PetSerAl sometimes I feel plain stupid. I read that - but did not process it. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ECMA final draft 2nd edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)

> When an operand occurs between two operators with the same precedence, the 
>   associativity of the operators controls the order in which the operations are performed: 
>    * Except for the assignment operators and the null coalescing operator, all binary operators are left-associative, meaning that operations are performed from left to right.
>
> > x + y + z
>
> is evaluated as
>
> > (x + y) + z.
>
> - The assignment operators, null coalescing operator and the conditional operator (?:) are right-associative, meaning that operations are performed from right to left.
>
> > x = y = z
>
> is evaluated as
>
> > x =(y= z).
>
> Precedence and associativity can be controlled using parentheses.
>
> > x + y * z
>
> first multiplies y by z  and then adds the result to x, but
>
> > (x + y) * z
>
> first adds x and y and then multiplies the result by z.